# Responsive design with Dojo

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, dojo, mobile-website

I'm currently endeavouring to make a fairly large non-responsive web application, responsive. The site is developed using Dojo Toolkit in a Single-Page Application approach, and is currently completely non-responsive.

By default, Dojo is not really geared towards responsiveness at all. I've done some googling on the topic of responsive web design and dojo, and have found a few threads regarding "dbootstrap", "Dojo Bootstrap" and some other edge cases. It seems that Dojo Mobile might also feed into this. But I guess I'm curious about real world experiences or approaches, has anyone had success creating a responsive website with Dojo? Or retrofitting a non-responsive dojo site in this way? It seems like quite a hefty task.

Comment: Maybe one won't agree but IMO Dojo is mostly designed for single page web application rather than fancy website. And as such, provides technics and component made for "almost desktop" applications. Most of the time applications are made with a desktop target not "all possible devices" target. Because of that "Reponsive" isn't the main focus of dojo

Comment: I agree with ben, I am adding here, that exists an effort from dojo to support more devices apart the desktop environment as "Dojo Mobile". Still dojo is a comprehensive framework with main target SPA application.

Comment: I understand your point @Ben and GibboK, and this application was originally created in that exact mindset. However even for SPA applications, the need to support mobile devices is increasing more and more. I was slow to come around to this, but I think to build even a rich web application specifically for a desktop target without considering responsive in this day and age is a mistake. I've found the "flat" theme provided by dojo which has helped a lot. But still having issues with Dialogs etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own customize theme in dojo and code it with responsive design responsive techniques, in this way you can create an ad hoc solution.

More information on Themes and Theming can be found at this link:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html